# Can I set the bokeh figure size across an entire jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

Using Matplotlib with the Jupyter notebook, I could set the figure size all matplotlib figures across the notebook with the notebook instruction:

```
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (14, 14)
```

Is there a similar instruction in `bokeh`? I have looked and only found references to the ability to set figure size in the `figure` function itself:

```
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(x, y,plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
```

But that means I have to program the size for each and every plot, etc. I was just wondering if this functionality exists in `bokeh` currently.

Comment: I don't think it does. You can write your own wrapper that calls `figure` with your preferred defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does appear to be a built-in way to set the default chart size.

```
from bokeh.charts import defaults

defaults.width = 450
defaults.height = 350
```

This should set the standard for an entire notebook.

**UPDATE**

The `bokeh.charts` subpackage has been removed in the current version of `bokeh` 0.12.10. This subpackage was supposed to move over to another `bkcharts` package but apparently `bkcharts` is no longer maintained. If you use the code above, you will get an error if the `bokeh` version is greater than 0.12.9.

The alternative is to just create a global variable named:

```
width = 450
height = 350
```

Then you can just reference these values in your plots. So

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
p = figure(plot_width=width, plot_height=height)
```

You will of course have to include this instruction for every plot in your notebook.

Comment: The last code block did not work for me. Instead, use your already existing figure and then do `figure.plot_width = 450` and `figure.plot_height = 350`